# boost::archive::text_iarchive constructor exception

Tags: c++, exception, serialization, boost, catch-all

I'm using Embarcaderro C++ Builder XE7 (which provides Boost library by default) on 64-bit Windows 7.

I find it odd, that constructor of boost::archive::text_iarchive throws some exception, as nothing seems to be misplaced. I found similar question on stackoverflow, but the problem was, constructor wasn't place in try block.

My code looks like this (note that this main() is actually function executed on button press, because I use C++ Builder. Pasting the whole code would be confusing and needless).

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbers1[10] , numbers2[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {numbers1[i] = i;}

    ofstream ofs("D:/Pulpit/file.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    if(!ofs.good()) return 1;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oar(ofs); //no exception
    oar << numbers1;

    fstream ifs("D:/Pulpit/file.txt", ios::in);
    if(!ifs.good()) return 1;
    boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ifs); //exception
    iar >> numbers2;
}
```

As you can see, it's just definition of iarchive, with std::ifstream parameter, which is properly opened (because of if(!ifs.good())). However I still get exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception. What's really odd is that I can't handle it in any way. Even catch(...) doesn't catch it and my program terminates.

I'm sure exception is thrown by costructor (or maybe destructor?)- everything works fine after commenting out last two lines.

Output class - oarchive - doesn't throw exceptions. It seems to serialize everything fine, but I can't read it then. If I try to use stringstreams instead of fstreams, thus excluding file failure, the same things happen.

Comment: Can you actually read the file? And verify the contents without using a file (e.g. write to a std::stringstream and read it back?). In other words, can you reduce and eliminate?

Comment: @sehe Yes, using ostringstream and istringstream, gave same results (output seems to work, input crashes), except even truncating input stream doesn't prevent exception in constructor (also uncatchable).

Comment: in that case, post the self contained example so we can actually fix things :)

Comment: Done. I didn't post actual code, because it's windows application, so a lot of unimportant stuff would appear. I hope int main() will be sufficient.

Comment: Ok, answered. Ironically, the behavior appears to  depend on compiler/platform then: [stringstream not crashing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d65513c95315b5d). But as I show in my answer it is better to be explicit about what you want anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must close the output file/archive before opening it as input.

Otherwise not the full archive will have been flushed:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b03e0e9fdcdf1e37)</kbd>**

```
{
    std::ofstream ofs("file.txt");
    if (!ofs.good())
        return 1;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oar(ofs); // no exception
    oar << numbers1;
}

{
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");
    if (!ifs.good())
        return 1;
    boost::archive::text_iarchive iar(ifs); // no exception!
    iar >> numbers2;
}
```

The stringstream solution: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e77597bd757e726)</kbd>**

Output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that was exactly the problem!